# Access a field from an unknown Groovy class in Java

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I have a Groovy class:

```
class SomeGroovyThing {
    String name
}
```

And in Java I receive a reference to an instance of this class as an Object:

```
Object o = project.getExtensions().getByName("groovyThing")
```

I can't cast the Object because I don't have access to the Groovy class in Java (for unrelated reasons). How can I retrieve the value of the `name` property (i.e. I want to do `o.name` but obviously that doesn't work).

I am wanting to do some sort of Reflection, but the fact that my Object is a Groovy class is throwing a wrench in things.

Comment: If `getByName` returns an Object of `SomeGroovyThing` then why do you think you can't cast it. Also, you don't need source code for casting. Only you need to have the class available on your classpath.

Comment: It’s not in my classpath. That’s what I meant. The groovy class lives in a totally separate repo that for other reasons cannot be used as a dependency.

Comment: By class, I mean the complied class (or maybe jar) and that class/jar must be on your classpath.

Comment: Yes I know, and I preferably want a way to do this without having it on my classpath (long story why...won’t explain here). I.e a solution that uses something similar to Reflection but that works with a class from Groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Reflection.

You can get it:

```
String name=(String)o.getClass().getField("name").get(o);
```

Or set it:

```
o.getClass().getField("name").set(o,name);
```

If `name` is `private`, you can set or get it using the setter/getter methods(`getMethod()` in `Class`) or use `setAccessible(true)` on the `Field`.